# Why do WebGL fragment shaders slow down over time on mobile?

Tags: android, ios, shader, webgl

I cannot find any WebGL fragment shader that will maintain 60fps in a mobile browser. They will run smoothly at first, but over the course of a few minutes will inexorably slow and stutter.

Here's a simple example to demonstrate the problem. http://glslsandbox.com/e#74134.2

Here it is running for a few minutes on iPadOS. https://youtu.be/oVPVER9RCP0

Are shaders like this simply not an option on mobile devices?

**Update:** This apparently only applies to WebGL1 contexts. On websites that use WebGL2, such as ShaderToy, the shaders run smoothly.

Comment: I think it's a power-saving feature related to request animation frame rather than webgl in particular, not sure what the heuristic is, user-interaction is probably part of the equation, maybe call consistency, as in if the animation loop is always running the same commands it may be categorized as some power virus. Real world applications never showed that kind of behavior for me, neither on android nor on iOS.

Comment: FYI, here's some [possible reasons](https://mattperry.is/writing-code/browsers-may-throttle-requestanimationframe-to-30fps) also be sure to request `high-performance` as `powerPreference` when [initializing the context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/getContext).

Comment: The framerate stay smooth. The precision of the circle position deteriorate as time gets bigger. The issue appear more quickly with lowp precision, and less quickly with highp. You can also "emulate" the issue on desktop by offseting time by a large constant. lowp float t = time + 1000000.0;

Comment: @pleup That's interesting, you're right! Do you know why this happens? Is there a way to have a continuous sin function of time without losing precision in the long term?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out. As pleup surmised, it was a problem of precision.

On every single shader I tested, the motion in some way relied on a function that required a precise decimal value time input. As any floating-point value increases, it gets less precise on this scale. So when this happens to the time uniform, it gives the *appearance* of poor performance.

So why does this only happen on mobile?

It's because desktop devices sometimes just ignore the global precision setting and use `highp` anyway. `mediump` is not precise enough for a minutes-long time value, but you wouldn't be able to tell on a machine that doesn't use `mediump` anyway.

So in the end, the fix is to force the precision of the time value by declaring it as `uniform highp float time`.